# ruby aws sdk s3 deletion of objects in folders

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm using the aws sdk to delete an object (or objects) from a bucket, the problem is that keys that don't exist still get counted as successfully deleted, shouldn't the SDK raise an error that the key doesn't exist?

The other problem is that an object corresponding to a key that does exist isn't being removed but is returning as being successfully deleted.

EDIT:

The second problem only seems to be when the object to be deleted is inside of a folder, in the root it gets deleted fine.

Comment: can you provide the code?

Comment: It's ok, managed to work out what the problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DELETE object operation for Amazon S3 intentionally returns a 200 OK even when the target object did not exist. This is because it is idempotent by design. For this reason, the `aws-sdk` gem will return a successful response in the same situation.

A quick clarification on the forward-slash. You **can** have any number of '/' characters at the beginning of your key, but an object with a preceding '/' is different from the object without. For example:

```
# public urls for two different objects
http://bucket-name.s3-amazonaws.com/key
http://bucket-name.s3-amazonaws.com//key
```

Just be consistent on whether you choose to use a slash or not.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out what you can't have have '/' at the beginning of the key, which I didn't realise, not sure *why* it was there but it was screwing up the key.